# Router loses it's time

Tags: router, clock

I have a WRT54GX2 SRX 200 router, which until a couple of weeks ago, was
working happily, until one day it started to disconnect my network from
the internet, and today I realized that its internal clock is now on
Jan. 1st, 2000.
I was at the router dashboard when I realized that but the dashboard said that the date could be configured in the Setup tab, but when I went there, I found no place to setup the date.
I'm using Firmware Version: 1.01.22 and Loader Version: 1.00.05 by the
way, which are the latest I have found.

I'd like to try setting the date to the current, and see if it stays connected, I understand that date goes in every packet so it could be the cause of the connection reset from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there probably are a backup battery inside that has run out.

So try to open the device, find the battery and change it.

Comment: but, isn't that the reason why the clock was lost? do you think changing the battery will restore the clock to the current time? I don't think so.

Comment: A lot of devices sync time with a ntp server, and therefore disables the possibility to set it manually.

Comment: but this won't depend on the battery, right? it only needs to be turned on... or I'm wrong?

Comment: I think the battery is why you lost time, and I think ntp is why you can't set it manually. Two different things.

Comment: so both of them are not working then... I can fix the battery but not NTP